# Long term stability of bluetooth connections

Tags: bluetooth, hc-05, raspberrypi

I have two Arduino Megas with HC-05 on Serial1 connected to a Raspberry Pi 3b+ via bluetooth, using the HC-05 and the RPi's built-in bluetooth, and python's `pySerialTransfer` library to make the connections.

For reasons I am still trying to root cause, the bluetooth connection gets severed a few times an hour. Ideally, I'd get hours to perhaps a day between severed connections; is this a realistic goal?

Over a course of a few days, my testing has shown:

1. Mega#1 median connection duration is 10 minutes & 88 minute max duration; 25 bytes sent by RPi->Arduino, and by Arduino->RPi every 0.2sec
2. Mega#2 median connection duration is 38 minutes & 153 minute max duration; 4 bytes sent by RPi->Arduino, and by Arduino->RPi every 0.2sec

During this testing, they're completely stationary within about 12" of each other, so range should not be an issue.

My RPi code detects a lost connection by virtue of failure to receive a message within 5 seconds, and attempts to reestablish the connection, and that is successful about 80% of the time.  I have a second-tier of lost-connection recovery - resetting the HC-05 via an Arduino-triggered MOSFET - if a message isn't received by the Arduino in ~20 seconds, that works in the remainder of the cases, so I'm ultimately able to systematically recover within a max of about 30 seconds.  However, this lost connection for ~10-30 seconds every 10-60 minutes causes a poor user experience for my remote controls.

The Python errors given for about 95% of the failures are a lack of a receipt of a heartbeat message from the Arduino to the RPi python; about 5% give a unspecific `[Errno 5] Input/output error` error.

While I'm running down multiple theories via day-long stability tests (longer byte transmissions are more error prone? there's some bug in my Arduino code causing crashes, so remove all logic except the send/receive code to test?), I've read a few posts about how finicky & fragile bluetooth can be, and so I'm curious for some thoughts about the general goal / attempt to get a longer-term (hours to a day or more) connection.

Have folks been able to achieve this with the HC-05 on Arduino?  Or is a dropped connection every 10-60 minutes just something one needs to deal with through robust code?  Thank you.

Comment: Speaking only from my personal experience, I've found the Bluetooth implementation on RPi (the 3B+ in particular) to be virtually useless. I've spent hours troubleshooting, but it was never relaible, and in many cases would not connect at all. From reading other Q's on [RPi SE](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) I've formed the opinion that others have had similar experiences. Also, I think it's true that RPi 3B+ has only a single antenna for WiFi and BT - which of course makes things *difficult* if you need them both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ultimately found a solution, but for the benefit of others, wanted to share the tests that also did not prove fruitful. **TL;DR**: Reducing message rate from Arduino's to RPi solved the problem.

My hypotheses to test:

1. Hypothesis: Faulty Arduino code written by myself. Test: Remove all logic except read / write.
2. Hypothesis: Something to do with message size. Test: Add an extra arbitrary 80 bytes to the Mega#1 message.
3. Hypothesis: Too many small messages for RPi to deal with. Test: Reduce message frequency.
4. Hypothesis: Timing problem or other HC-05 fault as suggested by @stefan-wyss. Test: Swap modules with a 3rd one.
5. Hypothesis: Faulty RPi python code written by myself. Test: Return to basic python test harness that does nothing except exchange bluetooth messages.

Hypotheses #1 & #2 led to no appreciable difference in failure rate or failure mode.

However, hypothesis #3 was the winner, with both Arduinos running for 12+ hours so far with no severed communications.  (So I did not bother to test #4 & #5).

Specifically, in the original "problem code", there were 20 messages sent every second (and 40 read attempts; I have "overclocked" the receiving in relation to the sending make sure buffers don't fill up due to slight variations in RPi vs. Arduino clocks):

- 5 sends of 25 bytes by Mega#1 to RPi per second
- 5 sends of 25 bytes by RPi to Mega#1 per second
- 5 sends of 4 bytes by Mega#2 to RPi per second
- 5 sends of 4 bytes by RPi to Mega#2 per second

Some of those didn't really need that frequency to achieve my design goals; so I changed to:

- **1** send of 25 bytes by Mega#1 to RPi **every 2 seconds**
- 5 sends of 25 bytes by RPi to Mega#1 per second
- **1** send of 4 bytes by Mega#2 to RPi **every 2 seconds**
- 5 sends of 4 bytes by RPi to Mega#2 per second

So now, instead of the RPi receiving 10x/second, it receives 1x/second.  (It's still *attempting* to read 10x per second on each of the two Arduinos to minimize latency, but most of those return no data received). The RPI still has to send 10x/second (5x to each of the two Arduinos).

This simple change fixed the problem. I have no insight as to why the RPi couldn't handle the faster rate of message receipt; some benchmarking on my Python code showed that processing of the received heartbeat messages was not a bottleneck. But the important part, at least for me & the project, is that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth communication works with fixed time intervals that both communication partners have to agree during the advertising and connection phases. Such an agreement could be: "While connected, lets' meet every second. If one does not show up during 3 meetings, let's leave the connection state".

From this you can see that timing is a very important factor in bluetooth communication. So **both communication partners need a very accurate clock.** No two clocks have exactly the same speed, one is always lagging the other.

It could be that one or multiple of the clocks of your HC-05's do have too much clock drift, so the connection will be lost. Maximum clock deviation allowed for a bluetooth clock is ±40 ppm (i.e. ±40 parts-per-million!) over the entire temperature range.

You could check this theory with multiple HC-05s. If individual modules lead to individual connection lengths, then this could be your problem.

Comment: Thanks, Stefan - I'll add that to the test list, and will report back (even if to share still unknown) in a few days after I've run each test for a day or so. Appreciate it.

Comment: You can also measure the clocks directly at the crystal if you have access to a timer/counter measurement device and a low capacitance (<1pF) probe.